# set font style to list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a list view:

```
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/my_list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/listFontStyle"
/>
```

As you see above, I have set a style to the list.

The `listFontStyle` is defined under `res/values/styles.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="listFontStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I populated the list content in Java code. Basically I set a list of string to an adapter. Then set the adapter to the list view. (No problem in Java code)

**My problem is** the style I set to the list view is not working, the font size is not changing. Why?

*******UPDATE*************

Ok, **probably it is better to update my question to** : How can I set style to a `list view` which has no item layout file, but only populate list content by Java code with `simpleAdapter` and a list of strings?

Comment: I guess that you should add `style="@style/listFontStyle"`
on your list items and not directly on your list

Comment: As I said, I use Java code to populate the list, by using simple adapter and a list of string, how can I add the style to my item?? There is no item layout file at all in my case.

Comment: Then you need to have a custom_listitem.xml containing a textview and in that textview,you have to specify style.and while populating listview,you will have to give that xml file name instead of using default listitem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is an example of how you can do that :

```
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list_categories_item, new String[] { "categoryName" }, new int[] { R.id.categoryName });
```

here is the list_categories_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg_list_category_item">

 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/categoryName"
            android:layout_width="70dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="test" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="25dp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:shadowColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ****UPDATE****
I don't think it's possible.

You should really consider using item layout xml, it's no a lot of work and will be an proper solution.

Hope it helps